# How to configure Proguard with IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I'm trying to configure an Android app to use Proguard in IntelliJ IDEA 12, the problem is that by default IntelliJ includes all my library projects as injars, with apparently no way for me to change that behavior.

So, two question:

One, can I change this behavior?

Two, do I need to? If I'm using android-support-v4.jar, is it ok to have that as an injar instead of a libraryjar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries like android-support-v4.jar are injars for ProGuard, since they are part of the application that is deployed on the device. ProGuard processes them along with the application code. This can reduce the size of the application, improve its performance, and make it more difficult to reverse-engineer. For instance, ProGuard may be able to remove large unused parts of libraries.

Only android.jar is a library jar for ProGuard, since it is already present on the device. ProGuard needs it for its analysis, but leaves it unchanged and doesn't copy it into the output jar.

Comment: Is there any way to tell IntellJ to also include a bunch of JSON files? I have JSON files that include class names, so they need to be run through Proguard as well.

Comment: @thalador If you can add the JSON files to the libraries, they will be processed as well (see the ProGuard manual > Usage > -adaptresourcefilecontents).